# AWS Lambda Java Trigger Destination

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have a lambda that is triggered by a api gateway endpoint. I want to have my handleRequest method trigger another lambda by utilizing the destination option rather than calling another lambda in code. 
[image]
However, when my handleRequest method return, it does not actually trigger the destination lambda. I can't seem to find documentation on how to do this in Java.

```
    public GatewayResponse handleRequest(Map<String, Object> event, Context context) {
    //how do I make a call to the destination lambda?
    return new GatewayResponse("sent successfully",200, Collections.singletonMap("test", "working"), false);
}
```

Comment: 1) Recommend adding some debugging code to see if your "handleRequest" is even being executed. I.e. put a `System.out.println("I am here");` before the return.

Comment: 2) Your question is confusing in that you mention a lambda and a destination option and then have no code for those two items.

Comment: @TomSchorsch I initially thought whatever was returned by the handleRequest method would also be provided to the destination lambda as an event, however that is not the case.